# random number selection and generating function

Tags: probability, generating-functions

Suppose a number is chosen randomly between $\{0,1, \cdots 99 \}$. Let X denote the sum of the digits of the selected number. I am interested in the p.m.f of X.

###### Here is my approach:

Let $u =\{0,1, \cdots 9\}$, $v=\{0,1,\cdots 9\}$

Define $$ h = 10u +v $$ such that $$h=\{0,1,2,\cdots 99 \} $$

$$ f(x)=f(k)= \sum_{k} f(k=u+v \mid h)\frac{1}{100}$$
$k \in \{0,1 \cdots 18\}$

Using generating function solution:

$$ \begin{align}
f(k=u+v\mid h) = f(x) &= (1+x+x^2+\cdots + x^9 ) (1+x+x^2+\cdots + x^9 ) \\
&= \frac{1-x^{10}}{1-x} \times \frac{1-x^{10}}{1-x} \\
&= (1-x^{10})^2 \frac{1}{(1-x)^2} \end{align}\\
f(k=u+v\mid h) = (1-x^{10})^2 \sum_{k=0}^\infty {2+k-1 \choose k } x^k = (1-2x^{10} +x^{20}) \sum_{k=0}^\infty {2+k-1 \choose k }x^k$$

For each $k$, we fill up the table below using the formulation above. Thus:

$$k= 0 \implies {2+0-1 \choose 0 } =1   \\
k= 1 \implies {2+1-1 \choose 1 } =2   \\
k= 2 \implies {2+2-1 \choose 2 } =3  $$

For $k = 10$:
$$\begin{align}
&k= 10 \implies {2+10-1 \choose 4 } - 2 {2+0-1 \choose 0 } =9  \\
&k= 11 \implies {2+11-1 \choose 11 } - 2  {2+1-1 \choose 1 } =12-4=8  \end{align}$$

The table for $f(k\mid h) = \{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1 \}$ for $k=\{0,1,2, \cdots 18\}$.

Then $f(x)$ follows by dividing each value by $100$

Is this approach generally okay? Anything to improve here?